# Specflow with Autofac - Unable to load TechTak.Specflow.Infrastructre.IBindingInstanceResolver Version=2.2.0.0

Tags: asp.net, autofac, specflow

I have a project that uses Autofac for constructor level injection. For every service instance, repositories are injected to constructor. 
Now to start using SpecFlow for the project I am not able to instantiate the service for method calls. I have already added Specflow.Autofac plugin but now I am getting following error. I have checked all referenced assemblies versions and those are correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using SpecFlow.Autofac. Is this correct?
If so, it doesn't work with SpecFlow 2.2 at the moment.
For details have a look at this issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/959

Comment: Yes I am using SpecFlow 2.2 
Does that mean i need to downgrade?

Comment: If you want to use SpecFlow.Autofac, then yes, you need to downgrade. Or send a PR for SpecFlow.Autofac to add support for SpecFlow 2.2.

Comment: Thank you @andreas-willich Downgrading SpecFlow to 2.1 helped resolve the issue